# Async End called on wrong channel error when multiple WCF service calls Are Made

Tags: c#

I am using the following code to call async web service methods and for queue system used is rabbitMQ.

```
ResponseObject result = await Task.Factory
    .FromAsync((asyncCallback, asyncState) => 
        _proxyservice.BeginInsert(new 
            WCFCall(_authorizationHeader, activity),
            asyncCallback, asyncState), asyncResult => 
            _proxyservice.EndInsert(asyncResult), null);
```

When parallel requests come from the queue together and the first call above is still processing the other comes in and I get the error Async End called on wrong channel. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong here?

One thing I was thinking do we need to create another instance of the _proxyservice (this is a channel creates using channelfactory) or it doesnot matter?

Comment: That code won't work well if `_proxyservice` or `_authorizationHeader` can change. Can they change?

Comment: no it always call the same web server

Comment: but we create a new instance of _proxyservice when a new request comes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we create a new instance of _proxyservice when a new request comes in.

That'll do it.

The code `asyncResult => _proxyservice.EndInsert(asyncResult)` creates a delegate that calls `EndInsert` on whatever `_proxyservice` is current *at the time of the call*, not the time of the delegate creation.

A quick fix is to use a local variable:

```
var proxyservice = _proxyservice;
ResponseObject result = await Task.Factory
    .FromAsync(
        (asyncCallback, asyncState) => proxyservice.BeginInsert(new 
            WCFCall(_authorizationHeader, activity),
            asyncCallback, asyncState),
        asyncResult => proxyservice.EndInsert(asyncResult),
        null);
```

However, the `FromAsync` API is designed to be used without delegates in many cases, so this is IMO more simply expressed if you change the code from using [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-taskfactory-fromasync(system-func((system-asynccallback-system-object-system-iasyncresult))-system-action((system-iasyncresult))-system-object)) to using [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-taskfactory-fromasync-1(system-func((-0-system-asynccallback-system-object-system-iasyncresult))-system-action((system-iasyncresult))-0-system-object)):

```
ResponseObject result = await Task.Factory
    .FromAsync(
        _proxyservice.BeginInsert,
        _proxyservice.EndInsert,
        new WCFCall(_authorizationHeader, activity),
        null);
```